# how to generate canonical tag dynamically in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, seo, canonical-link, canonicalization

Need to add canonical tag in jsp

```
<link rel="canonical" url="http://www.example.com"/>
```

But i dont want to hard code the url value.

How can i achieve this.

I have tried using data binding techniques but in view source, 
link tag is shown as

```
<link rel="canonical" href="" data-bind="attr:{href: ko.toJS($root.seoURLCanonical)}"/>
```

instead of

```
<link rel="canonical" url="http://www.example.com"/>
```

while inspecting we can see canonical link tag as

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" data-bind="attr:{href: ko.toJS($root.seoURLCanonical)}"/>
```

Comment: Are you using AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `id` of the `html` tag and attach ViewModel to it:

Simple example:

```
<html id="htmlTag">
<head>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/knockout-3.4.0.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.js' />"></script>

    <link rel="canonical" data-bind="attr:{url: seoURLCanonical}"/>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var viewModel = {
            seoURLCanonical: "http://www.example.com"
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("htmlTag"));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the DOM inspector you will see:

[image]

Comment: through data-bind i am able to bind canonical value. But in view source it will not reflect

Comment: will it be okay? if url value is not visible in  view source